# Scala not handling non-explicitly typed closures for ':' functions

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, types, programming-languages, functional-programming

So basically I want to write a function that can be written like this:

```
{ println(_) } =: thing
```

Here I want it to actually do `thing.=:(println(_))`. Lets say for the sake of argument that `=:` has the following implementation:

```
def =:(block : Int => Any) {
    block(5)
}
```

So I try calling it the above way and I get:

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Unit
   required: Int => Any
             println(_) =: thing
```

I then try doing this:

```
thing.=:(println(_))
```

This way I get a nice `5` printed to the terminal. I then tried this:

```
{ value => println(value) } =: thing
```

This again failed and told me there is a "missing parameter type". I'm guessing that this is because Scala tries to parse/compile the function argument first in this case and doesn't guess the type as it would (I'm completely guessing here) when it is called the more conventional way (with the dot operator).

Could anyone shed more light on the problems here and also maybe suggest the best way to achieve something close to my original goal?

P.S. Sorry about the title. I'll rename it once I have a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type inference works left-to-right, even if symbolic method names of the `#:` form end up working right to left.  You can use a helper method if you actually only have one type:

```
def let(fi: Int => Any) = fi
case class Thing(i: Int) {
  def =:(f: Int => Any) = f(i)
}

scala> let(_+2) =: Thing(5)
res4: Any = 7
```

but this isn't an entirely satisfactory solution if you have many possible type signatures because you have to match the helper method name on the left to the required type on the right.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this with implicit functions? I'm guessing not as Scala wouldn't look for an implicit as there is no type rather than it being a mismatch. Also, if you know a reason could you add to your answer why type inference can't work right to left for these functions.

Comment: @Oetzi - It would be more work to make the type inferencer work from right to left.  There's no reason it can't be done in principle; it's just a limitation of the implementation as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you add the parameter type:

```
{ value:Int => println(value) } =: thing
```

I'm not a Scala expert myself so I can't provide a deeper explanation of what the inferencer can an cannot inference.

Comment: That does work but I am writing a DSL where every one of these closures will have the same input type so it would be quite monotonous.